# Yii2 Composer update fails: Undefined property: Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\Repository\AssetVcsRepository::$verbose

Tags: yii2, composer-php

When I try to update composer on a vanilla Yii2 install, everything goes well. When I try to update composer on an existing install with an IDENTICAL composer.json file, I get this error:

```
Undefined property: Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\Repository\AssetVcsRepository::$verbose
```

I have no idea where to look to debug this and am pulling my hair out. Any ideas?

Many thanks for any insights!

Answer (score 0):

I found it. A previous attempt had installed a vendor/fxp directory. The solution was to remove it, as documented here:

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/9794